# how to add data from openweathermap api to windowinfo in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openweathermap

I'm trying to get weather information from
 openweathermap api and display it in infowindow on google map per click point,i get the data from the previous marker and not from the current one.

```
var map;
        var markers = [];
        var s = "";
        function initMap() {
            var currentLat;
            var currentLng;
            var coords;
            var contentString;
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 40.295308, lng: 62.164714 },
                zoom: 4
            });
            // get lng and lat
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                currentLat = event.latLng.lat();
                currentLng = event.latLng.lng();
                coords = { lat: currentLat, lng: currentLng };
                getWeather(coords);
                addMarker(coords);
                s = "";
            });

            function addMarker(coords) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: coords,
                    map: map
                });

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: s
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                ///
            }

        }

        function getWeather(coords) {
            fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + coords.lat + '&lon=' + coords.lng + '&units=metric&appid=MYAPI')
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((myJson) => {

                    console.log(myJson);
                    s += myJson.name;
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Error: " + err);
                });
        }
```

I tried to work with a global string and I also tried several times to work with setTimeOut on the getWeather function but I can not get the information before sending the point to the map

Comment: Be careful with the scope of your function declarations. Both `initMap` and `getWeather` are available globally but `addMarker` is only accessible within `initMap`. I'm not sure if this is intentional but you should declare `getWeather` in the same scope as `addMarker`. Scope can get complicated see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating the global variable `s` with the result of an asynchronous call to get the weather. The call has probably not completed by the time `addMarker()` is executed and creates the `InfoWindow`.

You should call `addMarker` only when `getWeather` has completed successfully and avoid using the global `s` variable. Remove the current call to `addMarker` and change the method signature to;

```
function addMarker(coords, s) { ... }
```

Then alter the `getWeather` function;

```
function getWeather(coords) {
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + coords.lat + '&lon=' + coords.lng + '&units=metric&appid=MYAPI')
        .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) => {
                addMarker(coords, myJson.name);
        }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error: " + err);
        });
}
```